# Firebase: Authenticated user with full permissions gets PERMISSION DENIED on root

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Set rules in Firebase console:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Run in Chrome console:

```
> firebase.database().ref().set('foo');
```

Database tab of Firebase Console now reflects `foo`.

Set rules in Firebase console:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Run in Chrome console:

```
> firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
< A {W: 1, sa: undefined, u: null, oa: null, fb: nul…}
> firebase.database().ref().set('bar');
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
```

Firebase is set up to allow anonymous and Google users, both of which get PERMISSION DENIED when I attempt to read or write.

**EDIT**

I've added an example project here:

https://github.com/formido/react-firebaseui-web-stackoverflow-question

If I set my rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "44358340": { ".write": true }
  }
}
```

...and log in, the console will print `Timestamp written`.

If I set my rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "44358340": { ".write": "auth != null" }
  }
}
```

...and log in, the console will print PERMISSION DENIED.

The most relevant part of the code I'm aware of is:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref("/44358340");
        if (user) {
          const timestamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
          ref.set(timestamp).then((error) => {
            if (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
            else {
              console.log('Timestamp written');
            }
          });
        }
      }
      this.setState({loading: false, user});
    });
  }
```

It's hosted on an Amazon server. I thought maybe I had to set the `AUTH_DOMAIN` to the AWS host, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: is your code attaching a listener in anyway ?

Comment: There is an `onAuthStateChanged` listener which tries to set the DB the same way as above if the user changes. It gets a permission denied, also, which was the original problem that started this exploration.

Comment: Please can you share more code so that it's easier to check where exactly your listener is being added. The issue could be in delayed server communication.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsbin.com/qiqezip/1/edit?html,js,output with rule `"44358340": { ".write": "auth != null" }`.
If you're still having problems, please create a similar jsbin that reproduces those problems.

Comment: Yeah, that works with my credentials. At least now I have a minimal example that shows my account works and proves how database writing works. I can't fathom how to reconcile my Chrome console log, yet, though.

Comment: I've updated the question with notes and a github project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. See [discussion starting here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/47#issuecomment-306575343).

[Fix here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/commit/cb46f758fa4e49ba8c08ec5dd7b294071afa5231) and it was deployed in [Firebase 4.1.2](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.1.2).